# Unable to run Autokey Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: autokey

I am relatively new to Linux/Ubuntu (so please take it easy on me) and I am trying to install Autokey to use the text expansion functionality. I have tried installing it from the instructions on the Github page here - https://github.com/autokey/autokey#installation

However, no matter whether I follow the installation process under the Ubuntu/Mint/Debian section or the instructions to install via pip I cannot seem to get the program working.

The installation seems to be successful (running a 'which' command gives the path installed) but clicking on the icon does not launch the program.

I have also tried to install directly from Ubuntu/GNOME software manager but that also will not launch the program once installed.

I have tried installing both the GTK and QT frontends and neither will launch. I don't get an error message or anything. I have opened up the System Monitor to see if a process even appears (however briefly) and there's nothing.

Typing autokey-gtk into Terminal gives:

```
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/gtkapp.py:24: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GObject, GLib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/autokey-gtk", line 20, in <module>
    from autokey.gtkapp import Application
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/gtkapp.py", line 28, in <module>
    import service, monitor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/service.py", line 21, in <module>
    from iomediator import Key, IoMediator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/iomediator.py", line 107, in <module>
    from interface import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/interface.py", line 29, in <module>
    from Xlib import X, XK, display, error
ImportError: No module named Xlib
```

Can anyone please help? Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be more appropriate for [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com).

Comment: My guess is that this may be an issue with dependencies? but I seem to have all of the ones needed installed as far as Python. Pip gives a different error when I try to install that way and if anyone is interested in that I can paste here too. Thank you.

Comment: @KenY-N My bad. Can I easily cross-post it to that location?

Comment: Just copy the whole post and repost it over there. I've found that site helpful  for detailed issues like this.

Comment: I found this question over there which is pretty much the same as mine and it is getting no love. Worse, I can't even comment to *bump* it or anything since I don't have the reputation needed. I guess I'm just hosed perhaps..

https://askubuntu.com/questions/989945/cant-get-autokey-to-work

Comment: Have you done `pip install python-xlib`?

Comment: @KenY-N - Somehow the problem resolved itself and the app launched after a restart. Still not sure the issue. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

I am a newbie too and installed Autokey 0.90.4, which did not work for me either. Someone suggested I try 0.95.1 because the other version is 7 years old.
I installed the new version with some acrobatics from the Autokey Github page, using the PIP method. At 1st it did not work, but after doing `import setuptools` it did. That might be a coincidence since it was after installation of the Ak package itself.

I know this sounds convoluted, but I am not familiar (yet?) with Linux. Anyway 0.95 works for me.

Answer (score 0):

install module python-xlib and it will work, like this:
On Deb:

**apt install python3-xlib**

You might later need python autokey module as well:

**pip install autokey**